# MySQL Update only changes

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I've imported a file to a MySQL table and now I want to update an existing table only with the changes.

I'm trying this with a select first before doing it as an update.

Both tables have an unique id field and value fields.

The following query doesn't give any results although there are differences in the value field:

`SELECT a.id, a.value, b.value FROM a, b WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.value!=b.value`

When I try it with `a.value=b.value` it works, but I need the changes.

Any Ideas?

My goal is to update table a in the end with changed values from table b but I can't update everything because I don't want to change a "lastedit" field if there are no changes.

I can't change the structure of table a to an automatic "lastedit" field.

Comment: Does not answer the q but, better use join instead

Comment: if you don't get any results, then you don't have any records that have the same ID and different values...

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.value = b.value 
WHERE a.value <> b.value
;
```

But of course, this only updates anything if (as Marc B said in his comment above) the tables have corresponding id values.

Comment: This doesn't update anything. When i do `SELECT a.id, b.id, a.value, b.value FROM a, b WHERE a.id=b.id` i can see several records with same id and different value.

Comment: @RobertKaiser, perhaps if you could add a sampling of your data, it might help us determine the issue.